# How to inherit WIndows system env variables when running msys2 bash job in scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, bash, msys2

I have a scheduled job on windows to compile nightly build for my program. This has been done using Cygwin64, and my schedule job looks like

```
C:\Cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -c "/cygdrive/d/path/to/buildscript.sh"
```

Recently, I wanted to replicate this using MSYS2, and my `buildscript.sh` is working properly in the MSYS64 shell (`msys2.ini` has `MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` enabled). However, when changing the above command to

```
C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -l -c "/d/path/to/buildscript.sh"
```

my script fails. It turns out that the system environment variables are not copied to the bash session.

I would like to know if there is a command line option that I can inherit all system env variables in a bash session. I tried `set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` in a `cmd` session before calling the above command, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

create MSYS2_PATH_TYPE in your system variables,and set the value to 'inherit'.

then your new created bash.exe could inherit your system path.